# matching regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a string which should consist of alphnumeric characters only. Thus for validation I have the following code but it is not working for some cases.

```
p = re.compile(r'\w+')
bool(p.match("str"))
```

but this fails in certain cases like when `str = "we1}"` the result is true but it should be false while `str = ")we1"` returns false which is correct. Thus how can I handle all these cases correctly if I want my string to consist of only alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `^` (match the start of the string) and `$` (match the end of the string):

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'^\w+$')
>>> bool(p.match('str'))
True
>>> bool(p.match('str}'))
False
```

`^` is optional, because `re.match` matches at the beginning of the string.

See [search() vs match()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use line start/end anchors (`^ and $`) also:

```
p = re.compile(r'^\w+$')
```

Without `^ and $` your regex will match just `we1` and you will wrong success returned back.

Note: `\w` will match `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (alpha numerics OR underscore)